# Programs in netbeans do not terminate as they are done with execution but continue running on as "Running Tasks"

Tags: java, netbeans, jakarta-ee

My programs in netbeans do not terminate as they are done with execution but continue running on as **Running Tasks** appearing at the right bottom corner of the netbeans window. Each time I re-run my same program a new thread is added to the 'Running Tasks' even when the code is done with execution.

Why is this caused ?

How can I rectify this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems one of the **User Thread** is running, post code to get the exact answer

Comment: code is in several files.. so I am unable to post that.. I am running a web app project in netbeans. I have a main function in one file and through that I call the functions that I defined in other classes & libraries.

Comment: web app project with main .. it seems it starts some container which doesn't stop

Comment: actually I am defining the database abstraction layer so right I am using main function to send testing commands to database layer.. just for convenience for right now..

Comment: sorry I do not know how to work with a profiler.. when I try to terminate the program I get :  Java Result: 2147483647
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 32 minutes 33 seconds)

Answer (score 1):

This is an extremely old question but I stumbled upon this having the same issue. Here is how I solved it:

Close NetBeans, delete the NetBeans folder from `C:\Users\[your username]\AppData\Roaming\`, then restart NetBeans. WARNING: this will delete any specific settings you've set (i.e. font size/style, etc) so beware of that before trying this

Answer (score -1):

Your programming is not exiting correctly.  If it is a GUI make sure your main Frame is set to Exit on close, or that at least something is set to exit when the frame is closed.